# How to calculate limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln x-\ln(\lfloor x\rfloor!)$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

While uses plot on [www.wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%28floor%28x%29%2B1%2F2%29%20ln%28x%29-ln%28floor%28x%29%21%29%2Cx-1%2F2%20ln%28pi%29%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C20%7D), i found a problem:
The function $$f(x)=\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln x-\ln(\lfloor x\rfloor!)$$
approximate the function
$$g(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln\pi$$

Can you prove it?

Comment: I would try the exponential function on both, then the Stirling asymptotic series for the factorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Stirling's formula:

$$x!\sim \sqrt{2\pi x}\left( \frac{x}{e}\right)^x$$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)&=(x+\frac{1}2)\ln(x)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi x)-x\ln(x)+x\\
\\
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)&=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)
\end{align}$$

Note in your plot (and in your post), it should be  $g(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$

Here is the updated [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot%20%28floor%28x%29%2B1%2F2%29%20ln%28x%29-ln%28floor%28x%29%21%29%2Cx-1%2F2%20ln%282pi%29%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C20%7D)